# JavaFX ComboBox Dropdown Layout

Tags: layout, javafx, combobox, parent, borderpane

I have a BorderPane that in its `CENTER` has a a grid pane with 2 combobox. On it's `NORTH` , it has a header pane. And in its `SOUTH` has a pane with navigation buttons. The problem here is that when I click the combobox, the dropdown menu covers the `SOUTH` pane as you see in the picture. Is there a way to bind dropdown with the `CENTER` pane, so that it cannot go over any of the `SOUTH` or `NORTH` panes.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can control the number of visible items in the open dropdown using the `visibleRowCount` property on the dropdown.

> The maximum number of rows to be visible in the ComboBox popup when it
>   is showing. By default this value is 10, but this can be changed to
>   increase or decrease the height of the popup.

See [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html#setVisibleRowCount-int-).

Comment: As this app is going to be run on diff devices with larger or smaller height size i do not want to just specify statically the items size. Based on the height of CENTER pane i would like to have that amount of items and the dropdown to not lay over the SOUTH or NORTH pane

Comment: You could always calculate the height of one line in the dropdown based on the font for the system and determine the number of entries based on that and the height of the center.

Comment: Yes, but giving the height of the center does not guarantee that the dropdown will be fitted to it and not lay over the north or south panes